# coredns deployment fails looking for nodes even after fargate profile patch

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, amazon-eks, aws-fargate

Problem with installing fargate profiles and coreddns addon; I'm using terraform for some parts and `kubetctl` for others, the fargate profiles are created via terraform:

```
fargate_profiles = {
  kube-system-profile = {
    name = "kube-system-profile"
    selectors = [
      {
        namespace = "kube-system"
        labels = {
          name = "kube-system"
          k8s-app = "kube-dns"
        }
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Cost = "DaCost"
      Environment = "dev"
      Name = "coredns-fargate-profile"
    }
  },
  swiftalk-dev-profile = {
    name = "dev-profile"
    selectors = [
      {
        namespace = "dev"
        labels = {
          name = "dev"
        }
      }
    ]
    tags = {
      Cost = "DaCost"
      Environment = "dev"
      Name = "dev-profile"
    }
  },
}
```

I then install coredns addon again using terraform

```
resource "aws_eks_addon" "core_dns" {
  addon_name        = "coredns"
  addon_version     = "v1.8.3-eksbuild.1"
  cluster_name      = "${var.eks_cluster_name}-dev"
  resolve_conflicts = "OVERWRITE"
  tags              = { "eks_addon" = "coredns", name = "kube-system" }
  depends_on        = [kubernetes_namespace.dev]
}
```

I patched the coredns deployment for fargate

```
kubectl patch deployment coredns \
  --namespace kube-system \
  --type=json \
  -p='[{"op": "remove", "path": "/spec/template/metadata/annotations/eks.amazonaws.com~1compute-type"}]'
```

and then restarted

`kubectl rollout restart -n kube-system deployment/coredns`

however, the coredns pods are still in pending state

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-5766d4545-g6nxn   0/1     Pending   0          46m
coredns-5766d4545-xng48   0/1     Pending   0          46m
coredns-b744fccf4-hb726   0/1     Pending   0          77m
```

And the cloud watch logs point out to the pods looking for nodes to deploy instead of `fargate`

```
I0723 10:24:38.059960       1 factory.go:319] "Unable to schedule pod; no nodes are registered to the cluster; waiting" pod="kube-system/coredns-b744fccf4-hb726"
I0723 10:24:38.060078       1 factory.go:319] "Unable to schedule pod; no nodes are registered to the cluster; waiting" pod="kube-system/coredns-5766d4545-xng48"
```

Comment: We're also facing this issue. We have public and private subnets, with internet gateway and nat gateway, autoassign public ip on the subnets, We've tried using eksctl and it works when it makes it's own vpc but not when we specify the vpc and subnets. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I haven’t yet, but that’s a good point to know, we’ve raised issue with AWS support waiting on their response.

Comment: @AnadiMisra I am also hitting this. What did AWS support say?

Comment: @tm77 My problem was due to limiting CIDR to my vpn only, enabling private access endpoint fixed it for me. See my answer

Comment: Same issue here, and the solution for me was in the doc link that @AnadiMisra provided: `your VPC must have enableDnsHostnames and enableDnsSupport set to true`. Once I set these to true for my VPC, everything worked as expected, also without the need for patching anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the problem was that after enabling Cluster Public Access Endpoint I had limited to public CIDRs (of our VPN), which meant I had to either add pods CIDRS or enable private access endpoint as mentioned in this article

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-endpoint.html

It works now, and **there's no need to patch coredns deployment**